# How to do proofs for inner product spaces?

Tags: linear-algebra, inner-products

For this question, I'm having trouble with this proof. Here is what I have so far. Can anyone please help me out?

Use the triangle inequality to prove that

$||v-w|| \le ||v|| + ||w||$ for any vectors v and w in an inner-product space $V$.

$||v-w||^2$

= $ <v-w,v-w>$

= $ <v,v> - <v,w> - <w,v> + <w,w>$

= $ ||v||^2 -<v,w>-<w,v>+||w||^2$

Comment: Hint: $v-w=v+(-w)$.

Comment: $|\langle v ,w\rangle|\leq \|v\|\| w\|$.

Comment: So I just turn it into adding a negative absolute value and then use cauchy-schwartz?

Comment: Remember that triangle inequality is $||v+w||\leq ||v||+||w||$ for all $v,w \in V$. Try replacing $w$ for something (see what quasi said)

Comment: So continue with what I did except replace w with ||v+(-w)||?

Comment: And of course, you know that $||-w||$ is the same as . . .

Comment: Wait so ||v+(-w)|| = ||v||+||-w||=||v||+||w|| so the proof is true? Is that really all?

Comment: $\LaTeX$ aside...You can use `$\langle$` and `$\rangle$` to produce $\langle$ and $\rangle$

Comment: Ok but is what I said basically the proof?

Comment: $$||v-w||=||v+(-w)||\le||v||+||-w||=||v||+||w||$$
Note: It's not an equality all the way through, since one of the relations is $\le$.

Comment: So just change the second equality sign to less than or equal to and then that's the proof?

Comment: If you can correctly justify each step, then it's a proof. As Gonzalo Benavides suggested, by the triangle inequality, you have $||v+u||\le ||v||+||u||$ for _any_ vectors $v,u$. So in this context, just let $u=??$.

Comment: the proof is true because we can add a negative number, and by the triangle inequality, it's less than or equal to v plus absolute value w and then an absolute value is positive, so it equals v plus w right? Is that a correct interpretation?

Comment: In this context, the u is the w